# How to make an app work in another machine?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have created an app using Java which uses a PostgreSQL database for storing data.

However, after I finished polishing the app and compiled it into a jar & uploaded it to my friend's test environment, it didn't work anymore!

How can I solve this issue?

P.S.: Sorry for my poor English

Comment: "it doest work!" you really, really need to describe your problem more.

Comment: Does your friend have a running Postgres server?

Comment: Assuming you are connecting to PostgreSQL using JDBC, does your PgSQL accept incoming connections that are not from `localhost`?

Comment: no!! but i have to install postgres server in every machine that i want to run my app?

Comment: if i like to sell my app, how can i solve this?? build a exe that install postgres server too?

Comment: user102890, how can i configure this?

Comment: Does the postgres server need to be on the same machine as your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have developed an application and wish to share that application with multiple users. Your application connects to a PostgreSQL database, but because your users do not have the database they get errors when they execute your application.

To fix the above you need to determine if each user needs their own database - in which case a working PostgreSQL installation is a prerequisite to using your application.

If this is the case I suggest writing some SQL scripts to setup your database and provide them to your users with a README file explaining how to execute the scripts rather than bundling an installer into your application.

*or*

If your users share a database, make your installation available via the internet/Network or use a service such as Heroku, Amazon AWS RDS service or EnterpriseDB's cloud offerings (built on Amazon AWS).

If you can provide more details on which option you're using I'm sure you will get more specific help. If not, hopefully the generic advise above helps.

Answer (score 0):

**How to connect to a Postgres db that is not open to the internet:**

Make sure your postres db listens to localhost. It probably does already, but still:

Look inside

```
    /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
```

for the line

```
    listen_addresses='localhost'
```

The next file you want is

```
   /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Look for the line

```
   local    all    all    trust
```

This gives access to all user roles on all databases on **localhost**.

Now, you need to open up a tunnel from where your app lives to your db server. Assuming that your db listens to default port 5432, do

```
    ssh -v -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432 your_user@your_db_server
```

If running Windows, do this in cygwin, or corresponding in Putty.

Now your app can connect to your db on localhost:5432 i.e.

```
    jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your_db
```

Hope this helps.